# Combinations in one column over partition by another column - BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My table looks like this:

| animal | name |
| --- | --- |
| cat | A |
| cat | B |
| cat | C |
| cat | D |
| dog | C |
| dog | E |

I would like to get combinations with two values over column `animal` so that the result looks like this:

| animal | combinations |
| --- | --- |
| cat | A,B |
| cat | A,C |
| cat | A,D |
| cat | B,C |
| cat | B,D |
| cat | C,D |
| dog | C,E |

Comment: What would happen if you also had a row (rabbit, F)?

Comment: I wouldn't take it into the account @jarlh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.animal, 
  format('%s, %s', t1.name, t2.name) as combinations
from `project.dataset.table` t1
join `project.dataset.table` t2 
on t1.animal = t2.animal
and t1.name < t2.name
order by t1.animal, t1.name, t2.name
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do a self join:

```
select t1.animal, t1.name, t2.name
from tablename t1
join tablename t2 on t1.animal = t2.animal
                 and t1.name < t2.name

order by t1.animal, t1.name, t2.name
```